# Excel Removes Unreadable Content

Tags: formula, repair, advanced-filter

Whenever I included the formula below in my spreadsheet an error is created when the document is opened. The message says "We found a problem with some content in 'documentname.xlsm'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?" After selecting yes the sheet displays another message saying "Excel was able to open the file by repairing the unreadable content". Nothing in the document seems to change. However if I leave take out the formula it opens without a problem.

=OR(TEXT(D11,"mmm-yyyy")=TEXT($C$4,"mmm-yyyy"),TEXT(E11,"mmm-yyyy")=TEXT($C$4,"mmm-yyyy"),AND(D11>$C$4,D11

Comment: The problem seems to go away when I remove the VBA that uses the formula for an advanced filter. But I need the advance filter to show my data correctly. The VBA is:

Sub AdvancedFilterDates()
'
' AdvancedFilterDates Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'
    Range("D22").Select
    Range("Table3[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange _
        :=Range("QO3:QO4"), Unique:=False
        
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I was able to prevent the error by adding code to clear all filters and sorting prior to closing the document.

Private Sub WorkBook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ws                    As Worksheet
    Dim wb                    As Workbook
    Dim listObj               As ListObject

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "pob2017edit"
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each listObj In ws.ListObjects
        If listObj.ShowHeaders Then
            listObj.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
            listObj.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        End If
    Next listObj
Next ws
```